# Find Sum of multiple fields in formik

Tags: arrays, reactjs, formik, yup

I am trying to get the total sum of amount field which is in array format.

Result i want: Add value of multiple field of amount and show value in total but i couldn't access value of amount field outside component

i am using formik and yup. Is there ay way to add array value in formik ?

Errors: Cant add value of multiple amount field

[output.image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27zVC.png)

```
    <Formik
            initialValues={{
              bankData: [
                { bankName: "", branch:"", chequeNumber: "", amount: "" },
              ],

              depositorName: "",
              depositorEmail: "",
              depositorMobileNo: "",
              chequeDate: "",
            }}
            
            validationSchema={ChequeRequestSchema}
            

              onSubmit={async (values) => {
                let ChequeaccountDetails = {
                  branchId: bankDetails.branch,
                  accountName: bankDetails.accountName,
                  accountNumber: bankDetails.accountNo,
                  currency:bankDetails.currency,

                  email: values.depositorEmail,
                  chequeDate:values.chequeDate,
                  depositorMobileNo: values.depositorMobileNo,
                  depositorName: values.depositorName,

                  details:values.bankData, 
                }
                let result = await AccountServices.verifyAccount(ChequeaccountDetails,'POST','/save-cheque-deposit')
                console.log(result);
               if(result.data.status){
                localStorage.setItem('chequedata', JSON.stringify(ChequeaccountDetails));              
                Swal.fire({
                  title: 'Please visit your prefered branch with code: ',
                  text: result.data.data.token,
                  icon: 'success',
                  allowOutsideClick:false,
                  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',  
                  confirmButtonText: 'OK',
                  class:"cashpopup",
                })
              }
            }}
            
            render={({ values, errors, touched, onBlur }) => (
              <Form autocomplete="off">
                <FieldArray name="bankData"
                onChange={console.log}
                  render={arrayHelpers => (
                    <div>
                      
                        {values.bankData.length > 0 &&
                          values.bankData.map((_, index) => (
                            <div key={index}>
                              <div className="row ">
                                <div class="col ">
                                  <Form ref={formref}>
                                    <div formArrayName="cheque">
                                      <div class="row mt-5">``
                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <h4>
                                              On Whom Drawn (Bank){" "}
                                              <span class="required-star">
                                                *
                                              </span>
                                            </h4>

                                            <Field
                                              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                                              as="select"
                                              // value={banknamemenu}
                                              onClick={(e) =>
                                                handleBankBranch(e)
                                              }
                                              name={`bankData[${index}].bankName`}
                                              autocomplete="off"
                                              formControlName="bankName"
                                              className={`form-control shadow-none`}
                                            >
                            
                                              <option
                                                value=""
                                                style={{ display: "none" }}
                                              ></option>
                                              {Banklist.map((values) => (
                                                <option
                                                  value={values.id}
                                                  key={values.id}
                                                >
                                                  {values.name}
                                                </option>
                                              ))}
                                            </Field>
                                           
                                            {/* {errors.bankName &&
                                            touched.bankName ? (
                                              <div className="error-message">
                                                {errors.bankName}
                                              </div>
                                            ) : null} */}
                                            <div className="error-message">
                                              <ErrorMessage name={`bankData[${index}].bankName`} />
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <h4>
                                              Branch
                                              <span class="required-star">
                                                *
                                              </span>
                                            </h4>
                                            <Field
                                              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                                              as="select"
                                              autocomplete="off"
                                              formControlName="branch"
                                              name={`bankData[${index}].branch`}
                                              className={`form-control shadow-none ${
                                                errors.branch &&
                                                touched.branch &&
                                                "is-invalid"
                                              }`}
                                            >
                                              <option
                                                value=""
                                                style={{ display: "none" }}
                                              ></option>
                                              {testState == "true" ? (
                                                <option
                                                  disabled
                                                  style={{
                                                    color: "gray",
                                                    border: "1px solid gray",
                                                    cursor: "pointer",
                                                  }}
                                                >
                                                  No items Found
                                                </option>
                                              ) : (
                                                <>
                                                  {getbankbranch.map(
                                                    (values) => (
                                                      <option
                                                      value={values.id}
                                                      key={values.id}
                                                      >
                                                        {values.name}
                                                      </option>
                                                    )
                                                  )}
                                                </>
                                              )}
                                            </Field>
                                            {errors.branch &&
                                            touched.branch ? (
                                              <div className="error-message">
                                                {errors.branch}
                                              </div>
                                            ) : null}
                                          </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <h4>
                                              Cheque Number{" "}
                                              <span class="required-star">
                                                *
                                              </span>
                                            </h4>
                                            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                                              <Field
                                                autocomplete="off"
                                                formControlName="chequeNumber"
                                                name={`bankData[${index}].chequeNumber`}
                                                placeholder="Enter your cheque Number"
                                                className={`form-control shadow-none `}
                                              />
                            
                        </div>
                                            <div className="error-message">
                                              <ErrorMessage name={`bankData[${index}].chequeNumber`} />
                                              </div>
                                          
                                          </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <h4>
                                              Amount{" "}
                                              <span class="required-star">
                                                *
                                              </span>
                                            </h4>
                                            <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                                              <Field
                                                autocomplete="off"
                                                formControlName="amount"
                                                name="amount"
                                                value={handleamtinword[index]}
                                                onChange={(index) => {
                                                  handleamtall(index);
                                              }}
                                                // onBlur={(e)=>getTotalAmount(values)}
                                              //  onChange={handleamt,[index]}
                                                //  {(e)=>sethandleamtinword(e.target.value)}
                                                name={`bankData[${index}].amount`}
                                                placeholder="Enter Amount"
                                                className={`form-control shadow-none ${
                                                  errors.amount &&
                                                  touched.amount &&
                                                  "is-invalid"
                                                }`}
                                                />
                                              </div>
                                                {/* {handleamt([values],index)} */}
                                                <div className="error-message">
                                              <ErrorMessage name={`bankData[${index}].amount`} />
                                              </div>
                                            
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <br />

                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                          {index == 0 ? null : (
                                            <button
                                              onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                                              type="button"
                                              class="btn btn-danger float-right p-5"
                                            >
                                              <span>
                                                <img
                                                  src={deleteblack}
                                                  width="20px"
                                                  height="20px"
                                                  alt="delete"
                                                />
                                              </span>
                                              Remove
                                            </button>
                                          )}

                                          <button
                                           class="btn btn-danger float-right p-5"
                                            type="button"   
                                                                    
                                            // disabled={!(Formik.isValid && Formik.dirty)}
                                            // disabled={(values.bankData[index].bankName==" " || values.bankData[index].branch==" " || values.bankData[index].chequeNumber==" " || values.bankData[index].amount==" ")?true:false}
                                            // disabled = {Object.values(errors).length > 0 ? true : false}
                                            // disabled={!values.bankData[index]==" " ? true : false}
                                            onClick={(e,index) =>{
                                              getFormValue(e,arrayHelpers)
                                              // arrayHelpers.insert({
                                              //   index:index,
                                              //   bankName: "",
                                              //   branch: "",
                                              //   chequeNumber: "",
                                              //   amount: 0,
                                              // })
                                              // console.log(arrayData[index]);
                                            }
                                      } 
                                            
                                          >
                                            <span>
                                              <img
                                                src={adds}
                                                alt="add"
                                                width="20px"
                                                height="20px"
                                                style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}
                                              />
                                            </span>
                                            Add
                                          </button>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </Form>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          ))}
                        <br></br>
</FieldArray>
</Form>
         </Formik>
```